# Unable to find unity activity in manifest. UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

i had a problem when build an run Google CardBoard SDK for Unity.

some one can solve it?

I used:

- Unity 4.2
- Device: Lg - p925 ( android 4.04)

  the Console in Unity Edit show:
- Unable to find unity activity in manifest. You need to make sure orientation attribute is set to landscape manually.
  UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
- Installation failed with the following output:
  pkg: /data/local/tmp/Package.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

rm failed for -f, No such file or directory

2127 KB/s (9391146 bytes in 4.311s)

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

- Error building Player: UnityException: Unable to install APK!
  Installation failed. See the Console for details.

please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
```

Your Device is 15.

Answer (score 6):

About the message *Unable to find unity activity in manifest.*, try adding the following line inside the `<activity>` tag in **AndroidManifest.xml** (found in `Assets/Plugins/Android`):

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
```